# Scrape data from a table in R, cant find the data inside

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the flight arrivals data from the table presented here https://www.ifly.com/la-guardia-airport/LGA-airport-flight-status-arrivals with `rvest` in R.

No matter what I use to find the data (SelectorGadget, manual inspection in chrome, using postman program) I cant seem to find the data presented in the table, the closest I got is getting the headers of the table, by tracking its selector.
My suspicion is that there is javascript involved somewhere in between, but I'm not sure how to approach this in R.
Does someone has any suggestions? help.

Comment: If there is javascript involved, you'll have to use something like `RSelenium` that can execute the javascript for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website uses an API. Identified that using Google Chrome's network traffic.

```
library(rvest)
url<-"https://www.ifly.com/api/v1/airlines/track?queryby=airport&date=20181218&hr=1500&arrairp=LGA&rn=1545154808"
page<-html_session(url)
data<-jsonlite::fromJSON(readBin(page$response$content,what="json"))
data$data$flights
```

This is the URL -> `https://www.ifly.com/api/v1/airlines/track?queryby=airport&date=20181218&hr=1500&arrairp=LGA&rn=1545154808`

Comment: Wow thank you so much! My only question is how did you find it uses an API using Chrome's network traffic? Did you searched for the string "api" in the results? What should be the basic approach when I am encountered with similar problems?